# JavaFX launch(args) method throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

So I was trying to launch my JavaFX application and a stack trace error showed up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
```

And I wondered what was going. At the bottom of the stack trace it says there's a NullPointer at the launch(args) method. I tried everything but I couldn't get it to work. This is my code:

```
public class Main extends Application{
public void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

//START
//GUI

@Override
public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception {
    SplitPane fullpane = new SplitPane();
    //DECK
    ScrollPane deckscrollpane = new ScrollPane();
    AnchorPane deck = new AnchorPane();
    deck.setOnMouseClicked((e)->{
        System.out.println(e.getSceneX());
        System.out.println(e.getSceneY());
    });
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
    rec.setTranslateX(23);
    rec.setTranslateY(20);
    rec.setWidth(200);
    rec.setHeight(300);
    deck.getChildren().add(rec);
    deckscrollpane.setContent(deck);
    //MAP
    StackPane map = new StackPane();
    fullpane.getItems().addAll(deckscrollpane, map);
    fullpane.setDividerPositions(0.4f, 0.6f);
    Scene scn = new Scene(fullpane, 700, 700);
    primarystage.setScene(scn);
    primarystage.show();
}
}
```

I'm pretty new to JavaFX, and I was hoping someone fairly experienced can explain how I'm supposed to fix this. My IDE (Eclipse) isn't showing any errors in the code either. The error only pops up when I run the program. I installed the JavaFX plugin (I think it's called something like e(fx)clipse or somethin' like that). A little help?

Comment: It should be (probably is) `public static void main(String[] args)`. And you can probably drop this method altogether.

Comment: Apart from omitting the keyword `static` on your `main(...)` method, this looks fine. How are you running this? Is that the complete stack trace?

Comment: Haha yeah, how did I miss that? Dear me, I think this is the worst question in StackExchange's history. Nevertheless, thanks for bringing that to my attention guys :D And yes, that should be the complete stack trace.

Comment: _ I think this is the worst question in StackExchange's history_ are you sure? i post shit questions myself.